# python requests proxies not working for me

Tags: python, python-requests, environment-variables, airflow, slack

My code for reference:

```
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
proxyDict = {
    "all_proxy": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "http_proxy": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "https_proxy": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "ftp_proxy": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "ALL_PROXY": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "HTTP_PROXY": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "HTTPS_PROXY": "http://proxy.com:8080",
    "FTP_PROXY": "http://proxy.com:8080"
}

try:
    res = requests.post('slack_url', json={"text": "text"}, headers=header, proxies=proxyDict, verify=False)
    print('Success!')
except:
    print("unable to send a slack message")
```

When I run this code it simply runs as if the proxies were never read and times out. However, when I manually set my environment variables it works perfectly fine.

The issue is that I need this part to run as an airflow service and therefore need the proxy to be set when it is run.

The only thing I can think of is that the requests library requires an actual IP address and can't use proxy.com (just replacing the company URL, not the actual url I am using). In which case I would need a work around without using the IP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try this: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/ I think the dictionary can only use 'http' and 'https'

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up your `proxyDict` in the wrong way. You only need to set one proxy in that dict.

```
proxy = "https://proxy.com:8080"
proxies = {'https': proxy}
```

Then set this proxy in the request:

```
res = requests.post('slack_url', json={"text": "text"}, headers=header, proxies=proxies, verify=False) #you should never use verify=False as it's not secure
```

If you want to select a random proxy from a proxy list, just put all of your proxies in an array and randomly select one.

```
import random
myProxies = ["http://proxy.com:8080","http://proxy.com:8080","http://proxy.com:8080"]
proxies = {'https': random.choice(myProxies)}
```